# sql resultset order defined?

Tags: sql, sqlite, many-to-many

Say I've employee table where any employee can be related to any other employee (many to many). Each employee has many characteristics that are stored separately.

```
emp: id,name
related: name,emp1role,emp1id,emp2role,emp2id
chars: empid,name,value
```

I want to get all the characteristics of employees who are related via 'xxx' along with the relation. I am currently using this query:

```
SELECT c.empid, c.Name, c.Value
FROM chars as c, related as r
WHERE r.name='xxx' AND (r.emp1id=c.empid OR r.emp2id=c.empid)
```

This works and it gives related employees one after another i.e. if emp22 & emp43 are related via 'xxx' then I am getting chars of emp43 followed by emp22 and so on. This way I am able to know which two employees are related (which is needed). However, I want to know if this order is mere luck or is it well-defined. This is in SQLite.

If it is not defined way, how else can I do it? Also, I need to know their respective roles. I want to preferably do it in one query. Can you think of some other query?

Thanks in advance,
Manish

PS: These are not actual tables. They are here for simplicity of asking question.

Comment: Generally, if you don't explicitly specify an `ORDER` in SQL then you can get your results in any arbitrary order, certainly, that's what I've experienced with SQLServer...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In SQL, ordering of the result is undefined unless you have an explicit `ORDER BY` clause in your query. So I believe you want:

```
SELECT c.empid, c.Name, c.Value
FROM chars as c, related as r
WHERE r.name='xxx' AND (r.emp1id=c.empid OR r.emp2id=c.empid)
ORDER BY c.empid ASC
```

I tend to add a unique field (such as a primary key) at the end, to if not get an obvious ordering when there are multiple records matching in all other order fields, at least get *deterministic* ordering. But that's largely a matter of style and choice; it's by no means required.

Comment: Thanks. But I don't need to results sorted based on empid. I'll not be able to know which employees are related. Like I had said I get empids in order where the related ids come one after another. Something like: "emp21,emp20,emp24,emp14,emp45,emp02". Here, the relations are (emp21,emp20), (emp24,14) and so on. I need this relation which will be lost if I do ORDER BY empid.

Comment: Then I believe your best option is to introduce some field that is calculated somehow from the order in which they should appear. Either way, without an explicit `ORDER BY`, the ordering is undefined. Many RDBMs will return rows in the order they were inserted, but this behavior cannot be relied upon.